# How can I bind model in ASP.NET MVC CORE with special attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, json-serialization

In our project there is a code style that force us to use model with property name like camelcase-style

```
public class MyModelClass { 
   public int CountryId { get; set; } 
   public int CountryName { get; set; } 
}
```

But service, that invoke out REST-API transfer HTTP-body with parameters like 
`country_id` and `country_name`. And I can't map the http-query to my model in controller action. Is there in ASP.NET CORE MVC way to map properties like that

```
public class MyModelClass { 
   [SpecialAttribute("country_id")]
   public int CountryId { get; set; } 

   [SpecialAttribute("country_name")]
   public int CountryName { get; set; } 
}
```

Or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: If the incoming http body json is being deserialized by Json.Net (which I think is the default in core) you can tell it to use snake case by default: 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm

Answer (score 0):

[asp.net-core-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc) uses [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) to serialize and deserialize json. [You can view the documentation here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm).  That being said you can *easily* do what you want by simply using the [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm):

```
public class MyModelClass 
{ 
  [JsonProperty("country_id")]
  public int CountryId { get; set; } 

  [JsonProperty("country_name")]
  public int CountryName { get; set; } 
}
```